# Is it possible to access the key_name of an object from inside a jinja2 template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm using python google app engine with the webapp framework, substituting jinja2 templates for django templates.

I know you can get the key_name of an object from inside a handler method by calling it like so:

```
goody = object.key().name()
```

But is it possible to access the key_name from within the template logic? Something like this?

```
{% for object in objectList %}
{{object|key_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but is there some filter or hidden attribute I can use to get at the app engine key_name an object is stored with from inside the template without extra fiddling inside the handler method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jinja2 allows you to execute callables, just by using `()` according to the documentation here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#other-operators

So, this should work:

```
{% for instance in instance_list %}
   {{ instance.key().name() }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I swear I tried that before and it didn't work. But I must have gotten something wrong, because I tried now and it's working fine. Follow-up, is there any overhead for these callables? Would I be better off storing the value in a separate attribute if I need to do this for a lot of objects?

Comment: Depends, function calls are one of the most expensive operations in Python. If this is a hot piece of code, then, you would be better off storing them before hand in an intelligent manner to avoid executing functions. If this is not getting executed often, then it's fine. Be careful about premature optimization :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do `object.key.name` inside django template to access appengine datastore object's *key name*

Normally, you access *key name* in python code through `object.key().name()`

Django template automatically tries a few possible ways to interpret `object.key.name` to give you the value.