# GAE - Trouble Deleting Entity from key

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am having trouble deleting entities from keys in the GAE using python/ndb. I am able to retrieve the entity (problem) key from the page, but cannot figure out how to get it to delete. The GAE support page says it's as simple as retrieving the key and then deleting it, as seen below.

```
problem = problem_key.get()
problem.key.delete()
```

But this is not working. I'm pretty sure the key is being obtained correctly. The HTML looks like

```
{%for problem in problems %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ problem.tags }}</td>
        <td><script type="math/tex">{{ problem.content }}</script></td>
        <td>{{ problem.answer }}</td>
        <td>{{ problem.quiz }}</td>
        <td>{{ problem.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ problem.date }}</td>
        <form action="/deleteProblem" method="POST">
            <td><button type="submit" name="problem_key" value="{{ problem.key }}">Delete Problem</button></td> 
        </form>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And my python code looks like:

```
class deleteHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        prob_key = self.request.get('problem_key')
        problem = prob_key.get()
        problem.key.delete()
        self.redirect("/")
```

I'm getting:

```
problem = prob_key.get()     
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My best guess is that prob_key is getting assigned the actual unicode and so of course there is no `get()` method for it but I don't understand how to fix the problem based on Google's explanation of how it should function.

EDIT: Okay, been scouting around for a while and I've changed this line:

```
prob_key = self.request.get('problem_key')
```

to

```
prob_key = ndb.Key('Problem', int(self.request.get('problem_id')
```

because as far as I understand it, a key can be constructed in the following manner

```
ndb.Key('kind', 'id')
```

Unfortunately, I still cannot get it to work. I am now getting

```
   problem.key.delete()
AttributeError: NoneType has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: You haven't passed the actual Key object. Create a Key object from the passed string and then do delete operation.

Comment: And once you have a key object, you don't need to get the actual model instance; just call delete directly on the key.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried to get it, couldnt make it work. I added what I tried into an edit

Comment: @DanielRoseman I also tried delete on the key directly. prob_key.delete() and that didn't work either. I imagine I'm doing this wrong..

Comment: @quest2graduate18 1. pass `problem.id` as submit value, 2. query for this id 3. do delete\

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am using the 'get_by_id()' function but I think I'm performing wrong syntactically. I am still getting 'AttributeError: NoneType has no attribute key '

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the key object itself through the HTML page, but you can pass its `.urlsafe()` string representation.

So in your HTML display the string representation, like this:

```
value="{{ problem.key.urlsafe() }}"
```

And in your handler code restore the key from its string representation:

```
prob_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('problem_key'))
```

From [Retrieving Entities from Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#Python_retrieving_entities):

> You can also use an entity's key to obtain an encoded string suitable
>   for embedding in a URL:
>
> ```
> url_string = sandy_key.urlsafe()
> ```
>
> This produces a result like `agVoZWxsb3IPCxIHQWNjb3VudBiZiwIM` which
>   can later be used to reconstruct the key and retrieve the original
>   entity:
>
> ```
> sandy_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=url_string)
> sandy = sandy_key.get()
> ```

Comment: I'm now getting a template syntax error. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I'm using webapp2. The admin who edited my question tagged it with Django.

Comment: Probably because of attempting to call `urlsafe()` in the template itself, I just assumed it'd work like this, based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190204/is-it-possible-to-access-the-key-name-of-an-object-from-inside-a-jinja2-template. Try `problem.key.urlsafe` as well (in case that's indeed a django template). Personally I don't invoke object methods in the template, I do that in the handler code where I can sanitize the result before passing it to the template. You could do the same, say by adding an `@property` to the `problem`'s class, returning `self.key.urlsafe()`.