# Linking to entity from list

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a Consults page that lists consults in the datastore. The list loop is like this:

```
{% for consult in consults %}
 <tr>
  <td><a href="consults/#">{{ consult.consult_date }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ consult.consult_time }}</td>
  <td>{{ consult.patient_first }}</td>
  <td>{{ consult.patient_last }}</td>
  <td><span class="badge badge-warning">{{ consult.consult_status }}</span></td>
 </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

The handler is like this:

```
class ConsultsPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        consults = Consults.query().fetch(5)
        consults_dic = {"consults" : consults}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/consults.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(**consults_dic))
```

I want to know the basic concept behind how I make each consult in the list a link to go in and view information about that particular consult.

I understand I need to use a key to retrieve an entity but am unsure of the rest of the process.

**Edit**
I have added the line:

```
url = '/display_consult?key=%s' % consults.key.urlsafe()
```

to my ConsultsPage (where the consults are listed). The handler now looks like this:

```
class ConsultsPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        consults = Consults.query().fetch(5)
        consults_dic = {"consults" : consults}
        url = '/display_consult?key=%s' % consults.key.urlsafe()
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/consults.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(**consults_dic))
```

However I get this error:

```
url = '/display_consult?key=%s' % consults.key.urlsafe()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Also what do I put into the link href in my loop that lists consults? is it something like:

```
href="consults/{{ url }}"
```

Comment: You'd call `key.urlsafe()` for each `consult`, of course, not for `consults` - you want a link for each one, no? You might even be able to call it inside the template, depending on your templating language.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42423466/4495081

Comment: I just changed consults to consult and got the error NameError: global name 'consult' is not defined. Yes I want a link for each one.

Comment: Then why do you create only one url? You either create one for each entity and pass it tot he template via `consults_dic` or create one inside the template itself, like you do with the rest of the `consult` info.

Comment: Ok I will create the url inside the template loop. I have added it into the href as follows: href="/display_consult?key=%s % consults.key.urlsafe()" but I think my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it is - quotes in the wrong place - if you're doing python code. But in the template - not sure if it works, not all templates support calling functions, you may have to do it in python.

Comment: Im sorry I'm unsure how to format this - this is my first url encode with python. What is the correct formatting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136768/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-timothyaura).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Retrieving Entities from Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#Python_retrieving_entities):

> You can also use an entity's key to obtain an encoded string suitable
>   for embedding in a URL:
>
> ```
> url_string = sandy_key.urlsafe()
> ```
>
> This produces a result like `agVoZWxsb3IPCxIHQWNjb3VudBiZiwIM` which
>   can later be used to reconstruct the key and retrieve the original
>   entity:
>
> ```
> sandy_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=url_string)
> sandy = sandy_key.get()
> ```

So for each `consult` entity you can obtain a unique URL where you'd display the info about that entity. For example by using a URL parameter:

```
url = '/display_consult?key=%s' % consult.key.urlsafe()
```

And in the `/display_consult` page handler you'd obtain the entity like this:

```
consult = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.get('key')).get()
```

Comment: Added further info