# How to drill down from entity list to entity instance in Google Appengine?

Tags: python, entity-framework, google-app-engine

I have a list of entities, and want to use the entity key to link to more details of an individual entity.

```
class RouteDetails(ndb.Model):
    """Get list of routes from Datastore """
    RouteName = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def query_routes(cls):
        return cls.query().order(-cls.RouteName)


class RoutesPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        adminLink = authenticate.get_adminlink()
        authMessage = authenticate.get_authmessage()
        self.output_routes(authMessage,adminLink)

    def output_routes(self,authMessage,adminLink):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        html = templates.base
        html = html.replace('#title#', templates.routes_title)
        html = html.replace('#authmessage#', authMessage)
        html = html.replace('#adminlink#', adminLink)
        html = html.replace('#content#', '')
        self.response.out.write(html + '<ul>')
        list_name = self.request.get('list_name')
        #version_key = ndb.Key("List of routes", list_name or "*notitle*")
        routes = RouteDetails.query_routes().fetch(20)

        for route in routes:
            routeLink = '<a href="route_instance?key={}">{}</a>'.format(
                route.Key, route.RouteName)
            self.response.out.write('<li>' + routeLink + '</li>')
        self.response.out.write('</ul>' + templates.footer)
```

The error I am getting is `AttributeError: 'RouteDetails' object has no attribute 'Key'`.

How do I reference the unique ID of the entity in my [drilldown](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/one-window-drilldown/) URL?

Comment: `key` is all lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RouteDetails` object indeed has not `Key` attribute, so you will get an exception at `route.Key`.

To get an entity's key you need to invoke the `key` attribute/property: `route.key`.

But passing the entity's key directly through HTML does not work since it's an object. The `urlsafe()` method is available to provide a string representation of the key object that is OK to use in HTML.

So do something along these lines instead:

```
    for route in routes:
        routeLink = '<a href="route_instance?key={}">{}</a>'.format(
            route.key.urlsafe(), route.RouteName)
        self.response.out.write('<li>' + routeLink + '</li>')
```

See also [Linking to entity from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470443/linking-to-entity-from-list/42472890?s=10|0.7080#42472890)

Comment: I did that but got the following error:  

`routeLink = '<a href="route_instance?key={}">{}</a>'.format(route.key().urlsafe(), route.RouteName)`
TypeError: 'Key' object is not callable

Comment: Oops, `key` is an attribute, not a method. Fixed.

Comment: ah, so `urlsafe()` is a method applied to the `key` attribute. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the entity's `key` attribute is actually an `ndb.Key` object corresponding to that entity. Which *might* be what misled you initially.

Comment: That's why I used `Key` instead of `key`, yes.